# Change Port from my WCF Service on Client Side

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, service, web-config

Is it possible to restart my WCF web service on a new Port on client side?
Do I need to change the hard coded baseUrl on my server side so I can change it in Client side? Or do I need to change Endpoints(config) on my Client side?

this is the code that I have ride now:
WCF config file:

```
<service name="WcfService.Service1">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>

        <add baseAddress = "http://MYIPADDRESS:8000/myService/" />

      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService.IService1">

      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>


    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
```

Client side:
Config file:

```
<client>
        <endpoint address="http://MYIPADDRESS:8000/myService/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService11"
            contract="Proxy1.IService1" name="ServicePort8000" />
</client>
```

So what I want to do is to set the Port by myself on Client side:

```
Proxy1.Service1Client test = new Proxy1.Service1Client("ServicePort8000");

        String http = test.Endpoint.Address.Uri.Scheme.ToString();
        String host = test.Endpoint.Address.Uri.Host.ToString();
        String port = txtServerPort.Text;
        String localPath = test.Endpoint.Address.Uri.LocalPath.ToString();

        String adress = http + "://" + host + ":" + port + localPath;

        test.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(adress);
```

But this is not the way..
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean to change the server endpoint port or client endpoint port? I don't think it is possible that the managed endpoint on the server-side could be modified by the client-side,since the service is started by Port-listener, which requires the server permissions.

Comment: I want to change the Port of the service at runtime , maybe if I make a method in my service 'changeport(String port)' and call it on my client? But at this time this isn't working as well :: public void ChangePort(String port)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://IPADDRESS:PORT/Service1/");
            ServiceHost host1 = new ServiceHost
            (typeof(WcfService.Service1),baseAddress);
            host1.Open();
        }